# Unity Network ClientRpc issue. Does not sync

Tags: unity-game-engine, network-programming, rpc, unity-networking

I have two players and these players are hitting a ball. Whenever they hit, there is a chance that ball's color may change.( green or red ). But when a player hit a ball it changes ball's color for only himself, other player's ball is the same color. I want all players to see the same color. Here is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;   
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class ColorGreen : NetworkBehaviour
{

    // Use this for initialization
    [SyncVar]
    int temp = 0;
    void Start () {
        transform.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.green;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {



            if (!isServer)

                return;

            RpcCHANGE();


    }

    [ClientRpc]
   void RpcCHANGE()
    {
        temp = Random.Range(0, 2);
        if (temp == 0)
        {
            transform.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.green;
        }
        else if(temp == 1)
        {
            transform.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
        }

    }
}
```

Ball Object has network identity checked "Local Player Authority". Can you guys tell me what I did wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think that when you call `RpcCHANGE`, it is called on each network instance, running the code within the method separately. This means that the result of `Random.Range(0, 2);` is different for each client.

Instead, you could generate the random color in the update method, and pass the color to RpcCHANGE, causing each network instance to be changed to the same color.